# How do I create a function in R that will take in an interval or just a number and return the lowest value from that interval?

Tags: r, function

How do I create a function in R that will take in an interval or just a number and return the lowest value from that interval?

This is what I have tried so far

```
clean<- function (x){
  no_comma <- gsub(',',"",x)
  value1 <- str_extract(no_comma, "(\\d+)")
  value2 <- na.omit(value1)
  return(value2)
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of input to the function and the expected output

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

How about the following function?

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(5, 4, "3", "1,246")

clean <- function(x){
  
  value1 <- x %>%
    parse_number() %>%  
    na.omit() %>%
    min()
}
```